# liftweb rest server POST request

Tags: scala, rest, lift

I am trying to make a liftweb rest server that accepts `POST` requests for a small internal testing and call it through Spring framework's `RestTemplate#postForObject("http://localhost:9090/api/validate/", request, String.class);`. I went through [Simply liftweb's Chapter 11 REST](http://simply.liftweb.net/index-Chapter-11.html).

**My RestController.scala is**

```
 13 object RestController extends RestHelper {
 14   val data = LiftRules.loadResourceAsXml("/ValidationReply.xml");

 21  serve {
 22    case "api" :: "validate" :: _ XmlPost xml -> _ => <system>
 26             <id>TEST</id>
 27             <name>PILOT</name>
 28             <version>1</version>
 29             <ip_address>192.168.2.18</ip_address>
 30             <connector>
 31                 <id>UPD</id>
 32             </connector>
 33         </system>

124    case JsonGet("api" :: "validate" :: _, _) => JString("Validated")
125  }
126 }
```

When I request the server with `postUrl = "http://localhost:9090/api/validate"`, I get the **not found** error response

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
    <body>The Requested URL /api/validate was not found on this server</body>
</html>
```

When `restUrl = "http://localhost:9090/api/validate"`, I get second api called with reply `"Validated"`. How do I make the `POST` request in liftweb?

Comment: It seems that your POST url should be : `http://localhost:9090/api/validate.xml`. NOTE the .xml

Comment: No, same `URL /api/validate.xml was not found` error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is looking for a `POST` that is XML. As [per the source](https://github.com/lift/framework/blob/2.4.1/web/webkit/src/main/scala/net/liftweb/http/rest/RestHelper.scala#L218),

> it gets passed through A trait that defines the TestPost extractor. 
>   Is the request a POST, has JSON or XML data in the post body and
>   something that expects JSON or XML in the response.

I'm not sure if you are just making the request or if you are actually sending data. But, assuming you are just making a post request, I would try posting XML in the body. Otherwise, you could try rewriting the rule using `Post` instead of `XmlPost` like:

```
case Post("api" :: "validate" :: Nil, req) => 
          <system>
              <id>TEST</id>
              <name>PILOT</name>
              <version>1</version>
              <ip_address>192.168.2.18</ip_address>
              <connector>
                  <id>UPD</id>
              </connector>
          </system>
```

Comment: In above API, I need to request without `xml`, but the url dosn't work with or without `xml`. Not even `case "api" :: "validate" :: _ Post xml -> _ =>`

Comment: Does this work for you: `case Post("api" :: "validate" :: Nil, req) => `?

Comment: Yes, it works with or without `xml` data in request. \,,/ Please amend your answer, I will accept it.